# Dynamic data loading in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Need help on codeigniter. I want to load dynamic data in div section which 
   will be based on dropdown's(#assettype_id) selected value. I am using ajax 
   method call (basically calling controller method) on dropdown change event. I 
  am passing dropdown selected value as a parameter of ajax call and based on 
  dropdown's value result will load on div tag.Below code is working perfectly on 
  dropdown's first event change but when i select another value from dropdown 
  data will not get changed?? I checked event is firing on every change but not 
  loading new data based on selected value?? Why this is happening?? Thanks in 
  advance. Please help me....

```
<head>                                                                 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("body").on('change','#assettype_id',function(e){ //assettype_id is dropdown ID
        var categoryval = $('#assettype_id :selected').val();       
        e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({            // will call a controller method to fetch data
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: {id: $(this).val()},
            url: 'http://myurl/assignpc/'+ categoryval, //my controller method with dynamic value of category based on dropdown selection
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data)
                 {
                    $("#result").html(data);    // result is div tag id             
                 }  ,
         });
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
            <?php 
              $js1 ='id="assettype_id", class="dropdown"';
              echo form_dropdown('assettype_id',$drpassettype, set_value('assettype_id'),$js1) ;
            ?>
</div>
<div id="result"></div> // data from ajax call will display here
</body>
```

Comment: show your `categoryval` method also

Comment: What is the inline `onChange=show()` supposed to do? That's a little weird to have two onchange events on the same element.

Comment: onChange=show() is nothing to do. By mistake i forgot to remove it.

Comment: Ajax method is calling controller method:                                                                          
      Public function assignpc($assetid)  // here passing categoryval value//                    
             {
   $this->load->model('computer');
  $data['data'] = $this->computer->getComputerForAssignment($assetid);
  $this->load->view('assignpc',$data,false);                                                       
            }

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.